# How to select(id) or find_all(id) from a div with beautiful soup in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to get the all elements in div tag having particular id.

The page what I want to scrape with Beautiful Soup is like this:

```
<div id="scrroll-1747719577" class="wpsp_container">
          <ul>
                        <li >                

                  <p class="wpsp_img_box"><a href="http://jntukucev.ac.in/as-per-the-directions-of-government-and-jntuk-the-college-has-extended-holidays-in-connection-with-containment-control-and-prevention-of-covid-19-upto-14-04-2020/" title="As per the directions of Government and JNTUK, the college has extended holidays in connection with containment, control and prevention of COVID 19  upto 14-04-2020.">
                                    </a></p>

                  <div class="wpsp_detail">


                    <h3><a href="http://jntukucev.ac.in/as-per-the-directions-of-government-and-jntuk-the-college-has-extended-holidays-in-connection-with-containment-control-and-prevention-of-covid-19-upto-14-04-2020/" title="As per the directions of Government and JNTUK, the college has extended holidays in connection with containment, control and prevention of COVID 19  upto 14-04-2020.">As per the directions of Government and JNTUK, the college has extended holidays in connection with containment, control and prevention of COVID 19  upto 14-04-2020.</a></h3>
                     <span>March 27, 2020</span>                   

                    <p>Extension of&nbsp;holidays due to COVID-19</p>


                      <a href="http://jntukucev.ac.in/as-per-the-directions-of-government-and-jntuk-the-college-has-extended-holidays-in-connection-with-containment-control-and-prevention-of-covid-19-upto-14-04-2020/" class="wpsp_readmore">
                     Read More </a>
                                       </div>
                </li>
                                <li >                

                  <p class="wpsp_img_box"><a href="http://jntukucev.ac.in/the-students-are-informed-to-follow-the-circular-in-order-to-utilize-the-lock-down-period-productively-by-engaging-in-online-learning/" title="The students are informed to follow the circular in order to utilize the lock-down period productively by engaging in online Learning">
                                    </a></p>

                  <div class="wpsp_detail">


                    <h3><a href="http://jntukucev.ac.in/the-students-are-informed-to-follow-the-circular-in-order-to-utilize-the-lock-down-period-productively-by-engaging-in-online-learning/" title="The students are informed to follow the circular in order to utilize the lock-down period productively by engaging in online Learning">The students are informed to follow the circular in order to utilize the lock-down period productively by engaging in online Learning</a></h3>
                     <span>March 27, 2020</span>                   

                    <p>On-Line-Learning---ICT-initiatives-of-MHRD-and-UGC</p>


                      <a href="http://jntukucev.ac.in/the-students-are-informed-to-follow-the-circular-in-order-to-utilize-the-lock-down-period-productively-by-engaging-in-online-learning/" class="wpsp_readmore">
                     Read More </a>
                                       </div>
                </li>
                                <li >                

                  <p class="wpsp_img_box"><a href="http://jntukucev.ac.in/revaluation-results-for-ii-b-tech-i-semester-r17-regularsupplementary-examinations-octobernovember-2019/" title="Revaluation Results for II B.Tech I-Semester (R17) Regular/Supplementary Examinations, October/November-2019">
                                    </a></p>

                  <div class="wpsp_detail">


                    <h3><a href="http://jntukucev.ac.in/revaluation-results-for-ii-b-tech-i-semester-r17-regularsupplementary-examinations-octobernovember-2019/" title="Revaluation Results for II B.Tech I-Semester (R17) Regular/Supplementary Examinations, October/November-2019">Revaluation Results for II B.Tech I-Semester (R17) Regular/Supplementary Examinations, October/November-2019</a></h3>
                     <span>March 20, 2020</span>                   

                    <p>Revaluation Results for II B.Tech I-Semester (R17) Regular/Supplementary Examinations, October/November-2019</p>


                      <a href="http://jntukucev.ac.in/revaluation-results-for-ii-b-tech-i-semester-r17-regularsupplementary-examinations-octobernovember-2019/" class="wpsp_readmore">
                     Read More </a>
                                       </div>
                </li>
                                <li >                

                  <p class="wpsp_img_box"><a href="http://jntukucev.ac.in/revaluation-results-for-i-b-tech-ii-semester-r17-supplementary-examinations-december-2019/" title="Revaluation Results for I B.Tech &#038;  II B.Tech II-Semester (R17) Supplementary Examinations, November/December-2019">
                                    </a></p>

                  <div class="wpsp_detail">


                    <h3><a href="http://jntukucev.ac.in/revaluation-results-for-i-b-tech-ii-semester-r17-supplementary-examinations-december-2019/" title="Revaluation Results for I B.Tech &#038;  II B.Tech II-Semester (R17) Supplementary Examinations, November/December-2019">Revaluation Results for I B.Tech &#038;  II B.Tech II-Semester (R17) Supplementary Examinations, November/December-2019</a></h3>
                     <span>March 20, 2020</span>                   

                    <p>Revaluation Results for I B.Tech &amp;&nbsp; II B.Tech II-Semester (R17) Supplementary Examinations, November/December-2019</p>


                      <a href="http://jntukucev.ac.in/revaluation-results-for-i-b-tech-ii-semester-r17-supplementary-examinations-december-2019/" class="wpsp_readmore">
                     Read More </a>
                                       </div>
                </li>
                                <li >                

                  <p class="wpsp_img_box"><a href="http://jntukucev.ac.in/revaluation-results-for-ii-mca-i-semester-r17-regular-examinations-december-2019/" title="Revaluation Results for II MCA I-Semester (R17) Regular Examinations, December-2019">
                                    </a></p>

                  <div class="wpsp_detail">


                    <h3><a href="http://jntukucev.ac.in/revaluation-results-for-ii-mca-i-semester-r17-regular-examinations-december-2019/" title="Revaluation Results for II MCA I-Semester (R17) Regular Examinations, December-2019">Revaluation Results for II MCA I-Semester (R17) Regular Examinations, December-2019</a></h3>
                     <span>March 20, 2020</span>                   

                    <p>Revaluation Results for II MCA I-Semester (R17) Regular Examinations, December-2019</p>


                      <a href="http://jntukucev.ac.in/revaluation-results-for-ii-mca-i-semester-r17-regular-examinations-december-2019/" class="wpsp_readmore">
                     Read More </a>
                                       </div>
                </li>
                                <li >                

                  <p class="wpsp_img_box"><a href="http://jntukucev.ac.in/revaluation-results-for-iii-b-tech-i-semester-r17-regular-examinations-october-2019/" title="Revaluation Results for III B.Tech I-Semester (R17) Regular Examinations, October-2019">
                                    </a></p>

                  <div class="wpsp_detail">


                    <h3><a href="http://jntukucev.ac.in/revaluation-results-for-iii-b-tech-i-semester-r17-regular-examinations-october-2019/" title="Revaluation Results for III B.Tech I-Semester (R17) Regular Examinations, October-2019">Revaluation Results for III B.Tech I-Semester (R17) Regular Examinations, October-2019</a></h3>
                     <span>March 20, 2020</span>                   

                    <p>Revaluation Results for III B.Tech I-Semester (R17) Regular Examinations, October-2019</p>


                      <a href="http://jntukucev.ac.in/revaluation-results-for-iii-b-tech-i-semester-r17-regular-examinations-october-2019/" class="wpsp_readmore">
                     Read More </a>
                                       </div>
                </li>
                                <li >                

                  <p class="wpsp_img_box"><a href="http://jntukucev.ac.in/results-for-i-b-tech-i-semester-r13-supplementary-examinations-january-2020/" title="Results for I B.Tech I-Semester (R13 ) Supplementary Examinations, January-2020">
                                    </a></p>

                  <div class="wpsp_detail">


                    <h3><a href="http://jntukucev.ac.in/results-for-i-b-tech-i-semester-r13-supplementary-examinations-january-2020/" title="Results for I B.Tech I-Semester (R13 ) Supplementary Examinations, January-2020">Results for I B.Tech I-Semester (R13 ) Supplementary Examinations, January-2020</a></h3>
                     <span>March 17, 2020</span>                   

                    <p>Results for I B.Tech I-Semester (R13 ) Supplementary Examinations, January-2020 Last Date for Revaluation/Recounting is extended 10-04-2020 &nbsp;</p>


                      <a href="http://jntukucev.ac.in/results-for-i-b-tech-i-semester-r13-supplementary-examinations-january-2020/" class="wpsp_readmore">
                     Read More </a>
                                       </div>
                </li>
                                <li >                

                  <p class="wpsp_img_box"><a href="http://jntukucev.ac.in/revaluationrecounting-results-for-mca-ii-semester-r13r16-regularsupplementary-examinations-june-2019/" title="Revaluation/Recounting Results for MCA II-Semester (R13&#038;R16) Regular/Supplementary Examinations, June-2019">
                                    </a></p>

                  <div class="wpsp_detail">


                    <h3><a href="http://jntukucev.ac.in/revaluationrecounting-results-for-mca-ii-semester-r13r16-regularsupplementary-examinations-june-2019/" title="Revaluation/Recounting Results for MCA II-Semester (R13&#038;R16) Regular/Supplementary Examinations, June-2019">Revaluation/Recounting Results for MCA II-Semester (R13&#038;R16) Regular/Supplementary Examinations, June-2019</a></h3>
                     <span>March 17, 2020</span>                   

                    <p>Revaluation/Recounting Results for MCA II-Semester (R13&amp;R16) Regular/Supplementary Examinations, June-2019</p>


                      <a href="http://jntukucev.ac.in/revaluationrecounting-results-for-mca-ii-semester-r13r16-regularsupplementary-examinations-june-2019/" class="wpsp_readmore">
                     Read More </a>
                                       </div>
                </li>
                                <li >                

                  <p class="wpsp_img_box"><a href="http://jntukucev.ac.in/results-for-i-b-tech-i-semester-r16-supplementary-examinations-january-2020/" title="Results for I B.Tech I-Semester (R16) Supplementary Examinations, January-2020">
                                    </a></p>

                  <div class="wpsp_detail">


                    <h3><a href="http://jntukucev.ac.in/results-for-i-b-tech-i-semester-r16-supplementary-examinations-january-2020/" title="Results for I B.Tech I-Semester (R16) Supplementary Examinations, January-2020">Results for I B.Tech I-Semester (R16) Supplementary Examinations, January-2020</a></h3>
                     <span>March 17, 2020</span>                   

                    <p>Results for I B.Tech I-Semester (R16) Supplementary Examinations, January-2020&nbsp; Last Date for Revaluation/Recounting is extended 10-04-2020</p>


                      <a href="http://jntukucev.ac.in/results-for-i-b-tech-i-semester-r16-supplementary-examinations-january-2020/" class="wpsp_readmore">
                     Read More </a>
                                       </div>
                </li>
                                <li >                

                  <p class="wpsp_img_box"><a href="http://jntukucev.ac.in/revaluation-recounting-result-for-ii-b-tech-i-semester-r16-iii-b-tech-ii-semester-r16-supplementary-examinations-october-2019/" title="Revaluation/ Recounting Result for II-B.Tech I-Semester (R16) &#038; III B.Tech II-Semester (R16) Supplementary Examinations, October-2019">
                                    </a></p>

                  <div class="wpsp_detail">


                    <h3><a href="http://jntukucev.ac.in/revaluation-recounting-result-for-ii-b-tech-i-semester-r16-iii-b-tech-ii-semester-r16-supplementary-examinations-october-2019/" title="Revaluation/ Recounting Result for II-B.Tech I-Semester (R16) &#038; III B.Tech II-Semester (R16) Supplementary Examinations, October-2019">Revaluation/ Recounting Result for II-B.Tech I-Semester (R16) &#038; III B.Tech II-Semester (R16) Supplementary Examinations, October-2019</a></h3>
                     <span>March 17, 2020</span>                   

                    <p>Revaluation/ Recounting Result for II-B.Tech I-Semester (R16) &amp; III B.Tech II-Semester (R16) Supplementary Examinations, October-2019</p>


                      <a href="http://jntukucev.ac.in/revaluation-recounting-result-for-ii-b-tech-i-semester-r16-iii-b-tech-ii-semester-r16-supplementary-examinations-october-2019/" class="wpsp_readmore">
                     Read More </a>
                                       </div>
                </li>

              </ul>

            </div>
```

I tried with this python code, but it does not work.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
page = requests.get("http://jntukucev.ac.in/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
c=soup.find(id="scrroll-1747719577") # not working
ids = [tag['scrroll-1747719577'] for tag in soup.select('div[scrroll-1747719577]')]#not working
#below method also not working
div_tags = soup.find_all('div')
ids = []
for div in div_tags:
     ID = div.get('scrroll-1747719577')
     if ID is not None:
         ids.append(ID)
```

All three returning nothing

I want all sub elements with in div tag having id: scrroll-1747719577 and plain text

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: It looks to me, that the id is dynamically generated. If this is the case, you are not able to query with a hard-coded id.

Comment: try using View Source in your browser.  if you don't see the tags you want, you're out of luck using a Python-only solution, as Javascript is probably adding it dynamically.  selenium or the like may help.  if you do see your tags, use console and `$("<css selector>")` until you get back what you want.  then copy your now-tuned css selector into python and use `soup.select("<css selector>")`

Comment: `css_selector = "#scrroll-1747719577"` should do the trick, `#` selects `id`s.  You know, if you're gonna scrape, some passing knowledge of CSS certainly beats random attempts.

Comment: Never mind `#<id>`.  This is what their html source says: `<!-- div id will be changed every time so please don't give css to id--><div id="scrroll-434597554" class="wpsp_container">`  So use css `"div.wpsp_container"` instead - which get a number of divs.  Such geniuses re. their obfuscation!  In any case, doesn't seem like you need Selenium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their html shows what you want in View Source and that means Selenium or the like is not necessary.  It is dynamic at the server end, but not injected in the client via JS.

However, this is also what it says:

```
<!-- div id will be changed every time so please don't give css to id-->
<div id="scrroll-434597554" class="wpsp_container">
```

So your CSS can't select via id.
Try using

`soup.select("div.wpsp_container")`

That will return all those divs.  You may have to filter yourself, or better, tune the CSS to return only those you want, based on other things in those divs.

At this point, I see little benefit of tracking the `id`, even in your parsing of what `soup.select` returns, as it varies everytime.

Answer (score 0):

For filtering/finding by `id`, you need to specify it as an attribute to `find()` or `find_all()`. Below is a skeleton code for your purpose -

```
for Tag in soup.find_all("div", attrs={'id':'scrroll-1747719577'}):
    DoSomething()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for the question:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
page = requests.get("http://jntukucev.ac.in/")
print(page)
print(page.status_code)
#print(page.content)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

c=soup.select("div.wpsp_container")
mylist=[]
for i in range(len(c)):
    d=c[i].select('a')
    for i in range(len(d)):
        mylist.append(d[i].get_text().strip())
print(len(mylist))
print(mylist)
```

Thanks to JLPeyret

Comment: Hey, txs for the txs, but an accept would be even better ;-)